# Express routes returning 404s

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I have a couple of simple routes that I have misconfigured and not sure why.

app.js:

```
//app setup
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var agent = require('./routes/agent');
var config = require('./config');
var app = express();


app.server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit : config.bodyLimit
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended : true
}));

app.use('/v1', routes);
app.use('/v1/agent', agent);

app.server.listen(config.port);

console.log('API listening on port ' + app.server.address().port);

module.exports = app;
```

This returns responses on the `/v1/` route (index.js):

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.status(403).json({
        message: 'Invalid request.'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

in the agent route, I have a POST handler that is being handled correctly at `/v1/agent/login`. But while a GET routed at `/v1/agent/` works, a GET routed to `/v1/agent/123` returns a 404:

```
'use strict';
var agentController = require('../controller/agent.js');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

function handleError(objError, res) {
    res.status(500).json({ errorMessage : objError.message });
}

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'OK' // works fine
    });
});

router.get('/:id'), function (req, res) {
    var agentNum = req.params.id;
    res.send(req.params); // 404 here

    try {
        //res.status(200).json({ message: 'hello agent.'});
    } catch (err) {
       // handleError(err, res);
    }
};


router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    var agentNum, password;
    // works fine 
});

router.post('/pwr', function (req, res) {
    //also works fine
});
module.exports = router;
```

My understanding is that the `app.use` method should redirect the route and any GET requests appended to that route to the one I specified (agent), so why is it that the one with params fails while the root one succeeds?

Thank you

Comment: not sure if this just wasnt included in your snippet, but i dont see a `module.exports=router` in your **routes/agent** file

Comment: @LostJon sorry - yes, it is present (just an oversight from my snippet)

Comment: change the order of routes, place `app.use('/v1/agent', agent);` before `app.use('/v1', routes);` Like this: `app.use('/v1/agent', agent);
app.use('/v1', routes);`

Comment: @RandomUser I gave that a shot earlier, did not work. It works sort of if I create a new route with the id appended to it `/v1/agent/:id` but when I continue to route it to `agent` it returns the default route at `/`, not the one I wrote for it that should handle the request params.

Comment: I keep scratching my head w/ this one...whats your express version? Also, does that try-catch ever get hit?

Comment: @LostJon 4.14, and I also updated the original question with the full content of the agent route file. And no - the try catch never fires (it is not correct in the question above but i can confirm it does not fire when that `res.send` is moved to the correct location in the method, simply returns a 404). Postman returns 404 every time I invoke that route via GET with a parameter. The others via POST work fine.

Comment: LOL, check the answer.

Comment: oh f** me ive been looking at this for too long...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing the callback correctly.

router.get('/:id'**)**

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    var agentNum = req.params.id;
    res.send(req.params); // 404 here

    try {
        //res.status(200).json({ message: 'hello agent.'});
    } catch (err) {
       // handleError(err, res);
    }
});
```

Comment: holy crap. the only solace I take in this is knowing two other people missed it at first too.

Comment: True Indeed., Well we three learnt something new today/tonight.